# Rhino Mocks - constructor fails when passing mock class as argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

EDIT:
I am entirely restating this question because I previously didn't articulate it correctly.

Everything except my test class is part of an API.  I am passing a mock interface into a mock class, and then passing that mock class into my test class.  My test class extends a class, and the body of the constructor is empty.  My code breaks at my constructor, meaning the failure is in the base class constructor, whose implementation is hidden.  I apologize if any of this is unclear, please let me know and I'll rephrase any parts that aren't clear.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is a code example:

```
public class TestClass : ApiClass0
{
    ApiClass1 apiClass1;
    public TestClass(ApiClass1 apiClass1) : base(apiClass1)
    { 
        this.apiClass1 = apiClass1;
    }
    public void MethodToTest() 
    {
        apiClass1.Method0();
    }
}

public class ApiClass0
{
    public ApiClass0(ApiClass1 apiClass1) { }
}

public class ApiClass1
{
    public ApiClass1(IApiInterface i) {}
    public Method0() { }
}

public interface IApiInterface0 {}

public class TestClassTest
{
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        IApiInterface0 mApiInterface0 = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IApiInterface0>();
        ApiClass1 mApiClass1 = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ApiClass1>(mApiInterface0);
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass(mApiClass1); //code breaks here
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean... why do you "need to be able to instantiate it first" if you're trying to mock it? The mocking framework would *create* the instance itself.

Comment: I don't suppose you can provide some sample code to illustrate your situation?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry that's what I meant, when I called GenerateMock (using Rhino) that's when I got the null reference exception

Comment: @tmakino: It's still not clear what the problem is. It would definitely be helpful if you could include sample code... (and this is the first we've heard of a NullReferenceException!)

Comment: "the null reference"? Again, this is the first we've heard about what actual error you're getting. Does `Complex` actually implement an interface? That should usually be what you mock, in my view. If it doesn't already implement an interface, could you *wrap* it in an interface of your own creation, and then mock that?

Comment: I wasn't asking my question the right way so I re-wrote it.  My main issue is that the constructor to my class is failing at the base class constructor.  I'm passing a mock into the base class constructor, and I can't see the base class constructor implementation because it's part of an API.

Comment: I've tried your code without any exception. I only had to fix coding errors like missing return value specification in ApiClass1.Method0() and wrong parameter type in ApiClass1 constructor.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the errors, I've edited them.  As I guessed the root cause is the base class I'm representing here as ApiClass0.  I tried calling GenerateMock on it directly, equivalent to how I'm calling it on IApiInterface0 and ApiClass1, but for this class it fails.  The implementation is hidden so I can't step into the constructor.  I'm looking at the Rhino Mocks docs to see what type of constructors can't be called using GenerateMock, but so far haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `ApiClass1` takes in `IApiInterface` as an argument, but the test invokes it with `IApiInterface0`. Change either of these, and the test will pass.